# Nelson's car and Lie bracket

Tags: lie-algebras

I just read Stillwell's Naive Lie Theory, had a very basic understanding about Lie bracket, then I ran into Prof Edward Nelson's book [Tensor Analysis](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Enelson/books/ta.pdf), where from 32 to 36, it discussed how to drive a car with the help of Lie bracket.

First, on page 32, it introduced a formula

> $$e^{t[x,y]} = e^{\sqrt{t}x} e^{\sqrt{t}y} e^{-\sqrt{t}x} e^{-\sqrt{t}y} + o(t)$$

Then started on a car model:

> Consider a car. The configuration space of a car is the four
> dimensional manifold parameterized by $(x,y,\phi, \theta)$, where
> $(x,y)$ are the Cartesian coordinates of the center of the front axle,
> the angle $\phi$ measures the direction in which the car is headed,
> and $\theta$ is the angle made by the ront wheels with the car. (More
> realistically, the configuration space is the open submanifold
> $-\theta_{max} < \theta < \theta_{max}$.)
>
> There are two distinguished vector fields, called Steer and Drive, on
> $M$ corresponding to the two ways in which we can change the
> configuration of a car. Clearly (15)
> $$\operatorname{Steer} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$$
>
> ....
>
> Then (16)
>
> $$\operatorname{Drive} = \cos (\phi+\theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial
> x} + \sin (\phi + \theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + \sin \theta
> \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$$

So far so good, then it said,

> By (15) and (16)
>
> $$[\operatorname{Steer}, \operatorname{Drive}] = -\sin(\phi+\theta)
>  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \cos (\phi+ \theta)
>  \frac{\partial}{\partial y}  + \cos \theta \frac{\partial}{\partial
>  \phi}$$
> named (17)

-- I'm lost here, how could I arrive to this result?

The first thought is this is just a calculation of the partial differentiation according to the chain rule:

$$[\operatorname{Steer}, \operatorname{Drive}] 
= \operatorname{Steer} \operatorname{Drive}
- \operatorname{Drive} \operatorname{Steer}
$$
$$
= \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}
\left[\cos (\phi+\theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial
x} + \sin (\phi + \theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + \sin \theta
\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\right] - \left[\cos (\phi+\theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial
x} + \sin (\phi + \theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + \sin \theta
\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\right]
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}
$$
$$
= -\sin(\phi+\theta)
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \cos (\phi+ \theta)
 \frac{\partial}{\partial y}  + \cos \theta \frac{\partial}{\partial
 \phi}$$

But... how could I map these to what I read from Naive Lie Theory?

As I understand, the essential idea of Lie theory is that given a curve in Lie group space $A(t)$, given $A(0) = \mathbf{1}$ where $\mathbf{1}$ is the unit matrix, its corresponding Lie algebra element would be the derivative
$\left.\frac{d A(t)}{dt} \right|_{t=0}$
, while at the same time for any element $A$ in the Lie group there's a corresponding Lie algebra $X$ such that $A = e^X$.

I tried to map as

- the configuration space is $(x,y,\phi, \theta)$
- the Lie group is the transforming matrix $A(t)$ at time $t$ so that
  $$
  \begin{pmatrix}
  x\\
  y\\
  \phi\\
  \theta
  \end{pmatrix}
  =
  A(t)
  \begin{pmatrix}
  x_0\\
  y_0\\
  \phi_0\\
  \theta_0
  \end{pmatrix}
  $$
- the change introduced by *Steer* and *Drive*, are the vectors in the Lie algebra, namely

$$\operatorname{Steer} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}, \quad
\operatorname{Drive} = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos (\phi + \theta) & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \sin (\phi + \theta) & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \sin \theta\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

- The Steer formula makes sense: if the driver only turns the steering wheel, after time $t$ the status is
  $$
  \begin{pmatrix}
  x\\
  y\\
  \phi\\
  \theta
  \end{pmatrix}
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
  x_0\\
  y_0\\
  \phi_0\\
  \theta_0 + \dot{\theta} t
  \end{pmatrix}
  =
  A(t)
  \begin{pmatrix}
  x_0\\
  y_0\\
  \phi_0\\
  \theta_0
  \end{pmatrix}
  $$
  so
  $$
  A(t)
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 + \frac{\dot{\theta}}{\theta} t
  \end{pmatrix}, \quad
  \frac{d A(t)}{dt}
  =
  \frac{\dot{\theta}}{\theta}
  \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
  $$
  Normalize it, we can say
  $$\operatorname{Steer} = \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}$$
  Now if we denote $\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}$ as $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$, then we can write as
  $$\operatorname{Steer} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$$
  So here I'm understanding $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$ as a notation of a unit in the Lie algebra, it's not a *real* partial differential that can calculate
- Similarly, when the driver only drives at speed $v$, denote the distance between the front and rear wheels as $L$, after time $t$,
  $$
  \begin{pmatrix}
  x\\
  y\\
  \phi\\
  \theta
  \end{pmatrix}
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
  x_0 + vt \cos(\phi + \theta) \\
  y_0 + vt \sin(\phi + \theta) \\
  \phi_0 + \frac{vt}{L} \sin(\theta)  \\
  \theta_0
  \end{pmatrix}
  =
  A(t)
  \begin{pmatrix}
  x_0\\
  y_0\\
  \phi_0\\
  \theta_0
  \end{pmatrix}
  $$
  so
  $$
  A(t)
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
  1 + \frac{vt}{x_0} \cos(\phi + \theta) & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 1 + \frac{vt}{y_0} \sin(\phi + \theta) & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 1 + \frac{vt}{L\phi_0} \sin(\theta) & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}, \quad
  \frac{d A(t)}{dt}
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{v}{x_0} \cos(\phi + \theta) & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & \frac{v}{y_0} \sin(\phi + \theta) & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & \frac{v}{L\phi_0} \sin(\theta) & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}
  $$
  Normalize it, we can say
  $$\operatorname{Drive} = \begin{pmatrix}
  \cos(\phi + \theta) & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & \sin(\phi + \theta) & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & \sin(\theta) & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}$$
  Now if we denote $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}:=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}, \quad
  \frac{\partial}{\partial y}:=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}, \quad
  \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}:=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}$$
  then we can write as
  $$\operatorname{Drive} = 
  \cos(\phi + \theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + 
  \sin(\phi + \theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial y} +
  \sin(\theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}
  $$
  Again here I'm understanding $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$ as notations of unit vectors in the Lie algebra, it's not a *real* partial differential that can calculate

But then I'm stuck.

First I tried to compute $[\operatorname{Steer}, \operatorname{Drive}]$ via matrix commuter, but I got
$$[\operatorname{Steer}, \operatorname{Drive}] = \operatorname{Steer} \operatorname{Drive} - \operatorname{Drive} \operatorname{Steer} 
= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos (\phi + \theta) & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \sin (\phi + \theta) & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \sin \theta & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
-
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos (\phi + \theta) & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \sin (\phi + \theta) & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \sin \theta & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This doesn't tally with (17) $$[\operatorname{Steer}, \operatorname{Drive}] = -\sin(\phi+\theta)
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \cos (\phi+ \theta)
 \frac{\partial}{\partial y}  + \cos \theta \frac{\partial}{\partial
 \phi}$$

Then I thought I have to use the formula $$e^{t[x,y]} = e^{\sqrt{t}x} e^{\sqrt{t}y} e^{-\sqrt{t}x} e^{-\sqrt{t}y} + o(t)$$
So I got

$$e^{\sqrt{t}\operatorname{Steer}} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & e^{\sqrt{t}}
\end{pmatrix}, \quad 
e^{-\sqrt{t}\operatorname{Steer}} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & e^{-\sqrt{t}}
\end{pmatrix}, \quad
$$
$$
e^{\sqrt{t}\operatorname{Drive}} =
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{\sqrt{t} \cos (\phi+ \theta)} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & e^{\sqrt{t} \sin (\phi+ \theta)} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & e^{\sqrt{t} \sin \theta} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}, \quad 
e^{-\sqrt{t}\operatorname{Drive}} =
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{-\sqrt{t} \cos (\phi+ \theta)} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & e^{-\sqrt{t} \sin (\phi+ \theta)} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & e^{-\sqrt{t} \sin \theta} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Multiply them together I still got

$$e^{\sqrt{t}\operatorname{Steer}} 
e^{\sqrt{t}\operatorname{Drive}} 
e^{-\sqrt{t}\operatorname{-Steer}} 
e^{-\sqrt{t}\operatorname{-Drive}} 
= \mathbf{1}
$$
Then
$$[\operatorname{Steer}, \operatorname{Drive}] = \frac{d}{dt}\left. e^{\sqrt{t}\operatorname{Steer}} 
e^{\sqrt{t}\operatorname{Drive}} 
e^{-\sqrt{t}\operatorname{-Steer}} 
e^{-\sqrt{t}\operatorname{-Drive}} \right|_{t=0}
= \mathbf{0}
$$
Also wouldn't tally with (17) $$[\operatorname{Steer}, \operatorname{Drive}] = -\sin(\phi+\theta)
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \cos (\phi+ \theta)
 \frac{\partial}{\partial y}  + \cos \theta \frac{\partial}{\partial
 \phi}$$

Pls enlighten me how the (17) formula shall be interpreted in the Lie algebra?

Answer (score 2):

There is some confusion going on when you represent elements of your Lie algebra as matrices. If we work in the basis $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}, \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$, we get:

$\begin{align}
\text{Steer} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \\
\text{Drive} &= \cos(\phi + \theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \sin(\phi + \theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + \sin(\theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \\
\vdots
\end{align}$

So, in this basis $\text{Steer}, \text{Drive}, \text{Wriggle}, \text{Slide}$ should not be written as diagonal matrices, but rather vectors with components given above:

$\begin{align*}
\text{Steer} &= \begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
1\end{pmatrix}, \quad
\text{Drive} = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\phi+\theta)\\
\sin(\phi+\theta)\\
\sin(\theta)\\
0\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}, \ldots$

From the book on *Naive Lie Theory* you may already know how to differentiate a Lie group into a Lie algebra, by taking the tangent space at the identity. It is also possible to integrate a Lie algebra into a Lie group: we can take any Lie algebra (like the one spanned by $\text{Steer}, \text{Drive}, \text{Wriggle}, \text{Slide}$) and find a (local) Lie group whose Lie algebra is the same as the one we started with.

One way to do this is via *Ado's theorem*, which involves representing the vectors in our Lie algebra as matrices. But we cannot do this in the same way you did; *we must make sure that the commutator is preserved*! If we represent elements of our Lie algebra as diagonal matrices like you did, then all the commutators become 0, since diagonal matrices commute. So we have represented the trivial Lie algebra, and all the calculations work out to 0.

What we have to do is find matrices $\text{Steer}, \text{Drive}, \text{Wriggle}, \text{Slide}$ satisfying (in what follows, the bracket is now a matrix commutator, and not the composition of derivation operators):

$\begin{align}
[\text{Steer}, \text{Drive}] &= \text{Wriggle}\\
[\text{Steer}, \text{Wriggle}] &= -\text{Drive}\\
[\text{Wriggle}, \text{Drive}] &= \text{Slide}\\
\text{all other commutators} &= 0.
\end{align}$

How do we do this? It's not so easy in general. The proof of Ado's theorem gives a general construction. I can post how the steps work, if you're interested. But the bottom line is that you can't represent elements in your Lie algebra as diagonal matrices corresponding to the vectors and then hope that the commutator is non-zero (it will always be zero): you have to choose your matrices carefully to make the commutator non-zero.

Comment: "How do we do this? It's not so easy in general. The proof of Ado's theorem gives a general construction. " -- pls can you post the steps? Also, I'm confused at you said $\begin{align*}
\text{Steer} &= \begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
1\end{pmatrix}, \quad
\text{Drive} = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\phi+\theta)\\
\sin(\phi+\theta)\\
\sin(\theta)\\
0\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}$ -- Steer and Drive both are vectors, how to compute the Lie bracket $[Steer, Drive] = Steer Drive - Drive Steer$? Differentiating Lie group get Lie algebra, Lie groups are matrices, so Steer as Lie algebra shall also be?

Comment: I'll post the construction when I have time, but I think I can answer some of your questions by talking broadly about the terminology of representation theory. In general, we say an "abstract Lie group" is just a group where differentiation is defined (possible to smoothly move between elements). An "abstract Lie algebra" is just a vector space with a Lie bracket defined. The reason for this definition is that some groups/algebras are easier to understand as these objects. For example, Steer and Drive are vector fields, so they have a vector space with a bracket.

Comment: "Representation theory" is the study of finding actual matrices that correspond to the "abstract Lie group" and "abstract Lie algebra." The book "Naive Lie Theory" probably skips talking about this step, because it's difficult and anyways most of the important relationships in Lie theory can be seen from matrix Lie groups and their Lie algebras. But when you have a Lie group/algebra that does not explicitly come from a matrix group, representing them as matrices is not easy (it is very interesting, though--try to find a book with "representation theory of Lie groups/algebras" to explain this).

Comment: @its-only-me pls post the construction details -- i'm slow to understand the abstract idea, a concrete example would, i suppose, visualize it and help me grasp the point.

Comment: @its-only-me when you are convenient, could you pls add those details? thank you

Comment: I'm working on it, it's quite a long writeup

Comment: @its-only-me thank you very much, working on something that's already obvious to you..

Comment: @its-only-me would you mind find some time write the details up pls?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You are confusing specialized techniques that are specific to the narrow context of Lie groups/Lie algebras with more general commutator formulas that apply on arbitrary manifolds.

Nelson's book starts with a general discussion of commutators of smooth vector fields on general manifolds (which are not necessarily Lie groups). The commuter of two smooth vector fields, also known as their Lie bracket, can be defined in this very general context as follows.

**Definition.** In local coordinates if the vector field $A$ is written as a first-order differential operator $A=\sum_j a^j(x) {\partial x_j}$  and similarly $B=\sum_k b^k(x) {\partial x_k}$ then their Lie bracket is another vector field  given by the operator commutator formula $[A,B]= \sum_{j,k} (a_j b^k_j \partial x_k - b_k a^j_k \partial  x_j)$.

Here e.g $a^k_j= \frac{\partial a_k}{\partial x_j}$.
As you noted in your post, this method for computing the commutator gives the result  mentioned in the book.

P.S. Later in Nelson's discussion he points out the remarkable fact that the fields  $A=$ Steer and $B=$ Drive can be augmented with two other vector fields to obtain a four- dimensional **Lie algebra**. That is, the commutators of these four fields with one another can be expressed as linear combinations of one another that have **constant** coefficients. (The property that these coefficients are constant is the distinctively "rigid" property of a true **finite-dimensional Lie algebra**).

P.P.S. In the typical case of arbitrary smooth vector fields on manifolds one would expect the commutators of  four arbitrary linearly-independent basis fields to be expressible as linear combinations of  these basis fields, but the expansion of each commutator in terms of this basis  would have **variable** coefficients. This is a much less rigid property than the former case of true Lie algebra.)

Comment: To add to your P.P.S. that is only the case over a 4-dimensional manifold (as in the example). More generally you wouldn't expect the span of 4 arbitrary vector fields to be closed under the Lie bracket. If they are we say they span an integrable (or involutive) distribution.

Comment: @MathWonk thanks for your explanation. Seems I shall read Nelson's book from beginning to get the differential geometry knowledge -- but the format is old (before latex) and the context seems also deep...

Answer (score 0):

In order to define the concept of vector fields in abstract, non embedded manifolds, one has to take a more abstract viewpoint, which is indipendent from the coordinates (because coordinates are defined only locally); one way is to think tangent vector as *derivations*.

For example, if you want to think the vector field $\mu:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n, x = 
 (x_1,\dots,x_n)\mapsto v_x=  (v_1(x_1,\dots, x_n),\dots,v_n(x_1,\dots,x_n))$ without using coordinates, you can consider the map

$$ C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n) \rightarrow C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n), f(x)\mapsto \frac{\partial f}{\partial v_x}(x), $$
in this way, you look at the effect that $\mu$ has on functions, rather than at its coordinates.

Observe that the map above, as any derivative, is linear and verifies the Liebnitz rule. So, in an abstract manifold $M$, you define vector fields as derivations of $C^\infty$ functions:
$$V(M) :=\{\mu: C^\infty(M) \rightarrow C^\infty(M) : \mu \ is \ linear \ and \ \mu(fg) = \mu(f)g +f\mu(g)\}.$$

Now $V(M)$ has a natural structure of Lie algebra, where the bracket of $\mu$ and $\eta$ is defined by
$$[\mu,\eta](f) := \mu(\eta(f))-\eta(\mu(f)).$$

If you have local coordinates $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, then you can prove that there is a unique form
$\mu = \sum a_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$, with $a_i$ are $C^\infty$ where defined, so you can apply chain rule, as you did in your calculation.